# Attempting to stop and then restart process using multiprocessing

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, raspberry-pi4

The goal of this file was to record data from a LiDAR sensor, then if the distance is too close stop the "sensorSweep" function or process "p2" and then when the distance is far enough away again, start to process again. Apologies for the messy code, this is my first project in Python.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        
        if ser.is_open == False:
            ser.open()
        p1 = Process(target = getTFminiData)
        p1.start()
        p2 = Process(target = servoThing.servoSweep)
        p2.start()
        while True:
            dist = getTFminiData()
            print('safe distance: ', dist)
            if dist <= 20:
                p2.kill()
                p2.join()
                print('too close', dist)
            if dist >= 20 and p2.is_alive() == False:
                p2.start()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:   # Ctrl+C
        if ser != None:
            ser.close()
```

Comment: What's you question?

Comment: I am getting an error for starting a process twice and would like to know how to work around this. Sorry for the lack of clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Once you kill a process it is done. You need to create a new one. This is a very resource intensive method however (creating a new process must re-initialize python, allocate memory, import modules etc). You should instead re-write `servoSweep` to look at some sort of shared `Lock` or `Condition` or simply a `Value` (from multiprocessing because only special explicitly shared values are accessible to separate processes a simple variable won't do). When the distance is over your threshold you can set / reset whatever your shared flag is.

```py
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

def servoSweep(do_sweep: Value):
    while True:
        if do_sweep.value: #check if the lock is locked
            # do a single sweep or part of a sweep here
        else:
            sleep(.1) #wait a little while so this loop doesn't waste cpu running super fast

if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_sweep = Value('c') #shared value will be an 8 bit unsigned int (char)
    servo_p = Process(target=servoSweep, args=(do_sweep,), daemon=True)
    while True:
        dist = getTFminiData()
        print('safe distance: ', dist)
        if dist <= 20:
            do_sweep.value = 0
            print('too close', dist)
        if dist >= 20:
            do_sweep.value = 1
```